# Moment returns invalid date when passed javascript date object

Tags: javascript, momentjs

This works when I get values like `2017-05-05T00:00:00`, or `May 15, 2017` but it always fails when passed something like `new Date();`. How do I get it to also accept javascript date objects?

```
moment.utc(dt, [moment.ISO_8601, 'MMMMDDY h:mm:ss A']).add(1, 'second');
```

EDIT ---

To be clear, this line fails with `invalid date` when `dt = new Date();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is failing because [utc()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) function of momentjs is expecting the first parameter to be a date `string` and not a `Date` object when you are passing the second String array as an argument. The following are the allowed Method signatures from Moment Docs-

```
moment.utc();
moment.utc(Number);
moment.utc(Number[]);
moment.utc(String);
moment.utc(String, String);
moment.utc(String, String[]);
moment.utc(String, String, String);
moment.utc(Moment);
moment.utc(Date);
```

Here is a working prototype for your query -

```js
var current = new Date();

var testDate = moment.utc(current).add(1,'s').format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss");

console.log(testDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When I pass `dt = new Date()` it fails with invalid date. Do I have to add a value to the format array?

Comment: Are you passing the `dt` object correctly to momentjs? can you post your code where you are trying to do this?

Comment: The line of code in the question is the whole thing. It's just that `dt` can be set a few ways. If I just fetched a date from the database, `dt` will look like `2017-05-05T00:00:00`. If I've already parsed the date for display and read the parsed HTML field it will look like `May 15, 2017`. If I create a new object with a date field, the date field will be set to the moment of instantiation via `new Date()`, so that one line has to handle all three input variants.

Comment: @Legion So, here the issue is that when you are getting the date from database or from HTML - its a string. However, when you are instantiating using `new Date()` its a date object. In case of a date object, you don't have to pass the second argument to `utc()` function.